# Is there any cost efficient way to find the number of docs in a collection in firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to firebase and I'm trying to integrate it into my vuejs project.
if I just want the number of docs in a collection instead of the actual docs, i read all the docs and use snapshot.size() to find the number. Is this cost-efficient? If not is there a better way to approach it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i read all the docs and use snapshot.size()

As the docs stays, this is what `snapshot.size()` is ment for. So you can go ahead with it.

> If not is there a better way to approach it?

Yes it is, you can implement `distributed counters` as explained in the [official documentation of distributed counters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters).

As a personal hint, don't store this kind of counters in Cloud Firestore, because every time you increase or decrease the counter will cost you a `read` or a `write` operation. Host this counter in [Firebase realtime database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) "at almost no cost".

Comment: Yes. The snapshot contains a number of documents, so you are charged for that particular number of documents. So the only billable reads that occur in Cloud Firestore are for those documents returned to the client.